# ellipsis+titletoc+…(utf character) : does it also cause a bug and how to solve it?

Tags: errors, unicode, titletoc, ellipsis

### The error

In the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc, ellipsis}

\begin{document}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{So…}

\end{document}
```

I get the error (when using `pdflatex`)

```
Undefined control sequence.
\textellipsis ->\futurelet \ellipsis@token 
                                           \@textellipsis 
l.7 \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{So…}
```

## My question

How can solve this issue and do you also encounter this bug?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Xelatex to compile twice, not pdflatex.

Comment: @Jesse I am not ready to use `xelatex`, I would like to use `pdflatex` is possible... Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: Then mark out \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}. Also see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization

Comment: @Jesse Using XeLaTeX wouldn't solve the problem, because `…` wouldn't use the ellipsis as defined by the package.

Comment: Hi, @egreg You mean the problem stated in your answer. OK, I saw the same error when using pdflatex but xelatex compiles fine. So, I did not see the problem you detected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a misfeature of `ellipsis` that redefines `\textellipsis` as a fragile command. Note that `titletoc` has nothing to do with this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{ellipsis}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\textellipsis

\begin{document}
x
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{So…}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! You guys are `TeX` geniuses!!!